# Taking html input and generating output

Tags: javascript, html, templates, input, output

Can someone help me get closer to doing what I am trying to do here?  I'm very new at html/javascript (obviously) and really don't know how to ask what I want.

I'm just trying make a template maker for craigslist.  Make an easy to use html page to send to people and have them fill in the input fields and have it spit out the html to post into the body of the CL posting block.

Any direction/guidance would be appreciated.  I've already spent about 3 hours on this and now don't know what to do.

Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><br>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><br>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Craigslist Ad Builder</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {margin: 30px;}
        </style> 

    <body style="margin: 10; padding: 10;"><br>
<!-- 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function multiplyBy()
{

            var numOne = document.getElementById("length").value;
            var numTwo = document.getElementById("width").value;
            var numOne = varLength.value;
            var numTwo = varWidth.value;            
}

        function multiplyFunction ()
{
            var sqftResult = numOne.value * numTwo.value;
                console.log(sqftResult);
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sqftResult;
}
    </script>
 -->
<script>
    function scrHTML(){
    var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    var bed = document.getElementById("bedrooms").value;
    var bath = document.getElementById("bathrooms").value;
    var model = document.getElementById("model").value;
    var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
    var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var sqft = document.getElementById("sqft").value;
    var sections = document.getElementById("sections").value;
    var newused = document.getElementById("new-used").value;
    var feature1 = document.getElementById("featureOne").value;
    var feature2 = document.getElementById("featureTwo").value;
    var feature3 = document.getElementById("featureThree").value;
    var feature4 = document.getElementById("featureFour").value;
    var feature5 = document.getElementById("featureFive").value;
    var link = document.getElementById("link").value;

    var htmlOutput = document.getElementById("htmlOutput");

    // htmlOutput.value = "<p> <b><u><h1>Contact info:</u></b> <br> <b>"+ name +" | "+ phone +" </h1></b></p><hr><h1>"+title+"</h1><h2>31905 IH 10 West Boerne TX 78006</h2><h2> Sale By: Agent/Broker</h2><h2>$"+price+"</h2><p><b><big><u>KEY FEATURES</u></big></b><br><b>Sq Footage: </b> " + SQFT + " sqft <br><b>Bedrooms: </b>"+beds+" Bed(s)<br><b>Bathrooms: </b>"+baths+" Bath(s)<br><b>Property Categoty: </b>"+newused+"<br><b>Manufacturer: </b>Oak Creek Homes<br><b>Width: </b>"+width+"<br><b>Length: </b>"+length+"<br><br><b><u>OTHER DETAILS AVAILABLE</u></b><hr><h2><b>"+newused+" 2017 Mobile Home from Oak Creek Homes<br>"+model+"</b><b><h3>Special Online Pricing - contact "+ name +" at "+phone+" for pricing sheet and more info!</b></h3><hr><u><b>Features that come STANDARD:</u></b><ul><li>"+feature1+"</li><li>"+feature2+"</li><li>"+feature3+"</li><li>"+feature4+"</li><li>"+feature5+"</li></ul><hr><b><h2>All this for only $"+price+" - call "+name+" at "+phone+" for more info or to come see the house!</b></h2><hr><ul><li>**Price does not include delivery, setup, or A/C</li></ul><hr>Additional Links: "+ link +"<hr><br><br>mobile home, manufactured home, modular home, tiny home, tiny house, cheap house, cheap home, palm harbor, clayton homes, palm harbor homes, titan direct mobile home, oak creek home, oak creek homes, mobile homes texas, mobile home san antonio, manufactured home san antonio, modular home texas, repo home, repossesssed home, foreclosure, foreclosed, cheap home, cheap house, used home, used house, single wide, double wide, triple wide, titan factory direct";
    htmlOutput.value = link
}

</head>

</script>   
    <form>
        Posting Title<br>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /><br>
        <br>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
        Phone:
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br>
        Price:
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" /><br>
        Bedrooms:
        <input type="text" name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms" /><br>
        Bathrooms:
        <input type="text" name="bathrooms" id="bathrooms" /><br>
        Model:
        <input type="text" name="model" id="model" /><br>
        Length:
        <input type="text" name="length" id="length" /><br>
        Width:
        <input type="text" name="width" id="width" /><br>
        Square Feet:
        <input type="text" name="sqft" id="sqft" /><br>
        Single or Double:
        <input type="text" name="sections" id="sections" /><br>
        New or Used:
        <input type="text" name="new-used" id="new-used" /><br>
        Feature 1:
        <input type="text" name="featureOne" id="featureOne" /><br>
        Feature 2:
        <input type="text" name="featureTwo" id="featureTwo" /><br>
        Feature 3:
        <input type="text" name="featureThree" id="featureThree" /><br>
        Feature 4:
        <input type="text" name="featureFour" id="featureFour" /><br>
        Feature 5:
        <input type="text" name="featureFive" id="featureFive" /><br>
        Link:
        <input type="text" name="link" id="link" /><br>

        <input type="button" value="Generate HTML" onclick= "scrHTML()" id="txtOutput" />

        <input type="text" id="htmlOutput" />
    </form>



    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: You should read craiglist API docs first and then answer yourself if you're able to utilize this knowledge in practice: https://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface. Starting web development by working with APIs is generally not a good idea if you ask me.

Comment: I appreciate the tip on APIs - I am not looking to send this information over to craigslist via their API.  I know what I wrote made it sound that way - my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. I've added a hidden div which will serve as the result container. When the user clicks the button the form will hide and the container with the output will be shown.

I've also cleaned up your code a bit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Craigslist Ad Builder</title>
    <script>
        function scrHTML(){
            var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
            var formDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];

            // the input values
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
            // etc..

            // here you can put your result html
            resultDiv.innerHTML = "<p>" + name + "<br/>" +  phone + "</p>";

            // hide the form and display the result div
            formDiv.style.display = "none";
            resultDiv.style.display = "block";

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
    Phone:
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br>
    <input type="button" value="Generate HTML" onclick="scrHTML()" id="txtOutput" />
</form>

<div id="result" style="display: none"> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the basic HTML structure should be like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers - below is what I've decided to use as the best answer.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><br>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><br>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Craigslist Ad Builder</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {margin: 30px;}
    </style> 

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function multiplyBy() {
        var numOne = document.getElementById("length").value;
        var numTwo = document.getElementById("width").value;
        var numOne = varLength.value;
        var numTwo = varWidth.value;            
    }

    function multiplyFunction() {
        var sqftResult = numOne.value * numTwo.value;
        console.log(sqftResult);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sqftResult;
    }

    function scrHTML() {
        var title = document.getElementById("title").value;
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var price = document.getElementById("price").value;
        var beds = document.getElementById("bedrooms").value;
        var baths = document.getElementById("bathrooms").value;
        var model = document.getElementById("model").value;
        var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
        var width = document.getElementById("width").value;
        var sqft = document.getElementById("sqft").value;
        var sections = document.getElementById("sections").value;
        var newused = document.getElementById("new-used").value;
        var feature1 = document.getElementById("featureOne").value;
        var feature2 = document.getElementById("featureTwo").value;
        var feature3 = document.getElementById("featureThree").value;
        var feature4 = document.getElementById("featureFour").value;
        var feature5 = document.getElementById("featureFive").value;
        var link = document.getElementById("link").value;

        var htmlOutput = document.getElementById("htmlOutput");

        htmlOutput.value = "<p> <b><u><h1>Contact info:</u></b> <br> " +
            "<b>" + name + " | " +  phone  + " </h1></b></p>" +
            "<hr>" +
            "<h1>" + title + "</h1>" +
            "<h2>31905 IH 10 West Boerne TX 78006</h2>" +
            "<h2> Sale By: Agent/Broker</h2>" +
            "<h2>$" + price + "</h2>" +
            "<p><b><big><u>KEY FEATURES</u></big></b><br>" +
            "<b>Sq Footage: </b> " + sqft + " sqft <br>" +
            "<b>Bedrooms: </b>" + beds + " Bed(s)<br>" +
            "<b>Bathrooms: </b>" + baths + " Bath(s)<br>" +
            "<b>Property Category: </b>" + newused + "<br>" +
            "<b>Manufacturer: </b>Oak Creek Homes<br>" +
            "<b>Width: </b>" + width + "<br>" +
            "<b>Length: </b>" + length + "<br><br>" +
            "<b><u>OTHER DETAILS AVAILABLE</u></b>" +
            "<hr>" +
            "<h2><b>" + newused + " 2017 Mobile Home from Oak Creek Homes<br>" + model + "</b>" +
            "<h3><b>Special Online Pricing - contact " +  name  + " at " + phone + " for pricing sheet and more info!</b></h3>" +
            "<hr>" +
            "<u><b>Features that come STANDARD:</b></u>" +
            "<ul>" +
            "<li>" + feature1 + "</li>" +
            "<li>" + feature2 + "</li>" +
            "<li>" + feature3 + "</li>" +
            "<li>" + feature4 + "</li>" +
            "<li>" + feature5 + "</li>" +
            "</ul>" +
            "<hr>" +
            "<b><h2>All this for only $" + price + " - call " + name + " at " + phone + " for more info or to come see the house!</b></h2><hr>" +
            "<ul>" +
            "<li>**Price does not include delivery, setup, or A/C</li>" +
            "</ul>" +
            "<hr>" +
            "Additional Links: " +  link  + "<hr><br><br>" +
            "mobile home, manufactured home, modular home, tiny home, tiny house, cheap house, cheap home, palm harbor, clayton homes, palm harbor homes, titan direct mobile home, oak creek home, oak creek homes, mobile homes texas, mobile home san antonio, manufactured home san antonio, modular home texas, repo home, repossesssed home, foreclosure, foreclosed, cheap home, cheap house, used home, used house, single wide, double wide, triple wide, titan factory direct";
    }

//-->
</script>   
</head>

<body style="margin: 10; padding: 10;"><br>
    <form>
        Posting Title<br>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" /><br>
        <br>
        Name:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br>
        Phone:
        <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" /><br>
        Price:
        <input type="text" name="price" id="price" /><br>
        Bedrooms:
        <input type="text" name="bedrooms" id="bedrooms" /><br>
        Bathrooms:
        <input type="text" name="bathrooms" id="bathrooms" /><br>
        Model:
        <input type="text" name="model" id="model" /><br>
        Length:
        <input type="text" name="length" id="length" /><br>
        Width:
        <input type="text" name="width" id="width" /><br>
        Square Feet:
        <input type="text" name="sqft" id="sqft" /><br>
        Single or Double:
        <input type="text" name="sections" id="sections" /><br>
        New or Used:
        <input type="text" name="new-used" id="new-used" /><br>
        Feature 1:
        <input type="text" name="featureOne" id="featureOne" /><br>
        Feature 2:
        <input type="text" name="featureTwo" id="featureTwo" /><br>
        Feature 3:
        <input type="text" name="featureThree" id="featureThree" /><br>
        Feature 4:
        <input type="text" name="featureFour" id="featureFour" /><br>
        Feature 5:
        <input type="text" name="featureFive" id="featureFive" /><br>
        Link:
        <input type="text" name="link" id="link" /><br>

        <input type="button" value="Generate HTML" onclick= "scrHTML()" id="txtOutput" /><br>

        <textarea type="text" id="htmlOutput" style="width:500px;height:300px"></textarea>
    </form>



    </body>


    </html>
```